# Existence of Linear Representation

Tags: utility, preferences

Consider a preference relation $\succeq$ on $X=\mathbb{R^2_{+}}$. If $\succeq$ satisifies:
$$
\begin{align}
&1.\mbox{ }(a_1,a_2)\succeq (b_1,b_2)\implies(a_1+t,a_2+s)\succeq (b_1+t,b_2+s),\forall t,s\\
&2.\mbox{ }a_1\geq b_1 \mbox{ and } a_2\geq b_2 \implies (a_1,a_2)\succeq (b_1,b_2)\mbox{ (and the analogous for }\succ\mbox{)}\\
&3.\mbox{ Continuity }
\end{align}
$$
Then: exists a linear representation for $\succeq$.

Could anyone give me some hints on how to prove this?

Thanks for helping! :D

Comment: You can look at Koopman's very famous Econometrica paper to have some insight on these kind of stuff.

Comment: I remember having seen this proof somewhere before, I tried finding it on Mas-colell but without success. Maybe your suggestion can help me somehow. Thanks! :D BTW, which paper are you talking about?

Comment: Here it is ;

http://mikael.cozic.free.fr/koopmans60.pdf

Comment: You could make this into an answer.

Comment: Who proposed this independence axiom? I cannot find it on Koopmans 1960

Answer (score 2):

How about this: For each vector $(x,y)$, there is a unique $z\in \mathbb R$ such that $(x,y) \sim (z,z)$. WLOG assume $x \geq y$. Then to see this claim, first notice by A2 that $(x,x) \succeq (x,y) \succeq (y,x)$. Then traveling along the $45^\circ$ from $(y,y)$ to $(x,x)$, A3 ensures the existence of our $z$. (Strict) Monotonicity assures uniqueness in the obvious way. Let $u: (x,y) \mapsto z$ where $z$ is defined in this way.

Now let $(x,y) \sim (z,z)$ and $(x',y') \sim (z',z')$. Then by A1 we have
\begin{align}
(x + x',y+y') &\sim (z + x',z + y') \\
(x' + z,y' +z) &\sim (z'+z,z'+z)
\end{align}
so by transitivity, $(x+x',y+y') \sim (z+z',z+z')$. Verifying that $u$ is continuous is trivial.

So $u$ is additive and continuous. As [this Math SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116223/proof-that-a-continuous-additive-homomorphism-mathbbrn-to-mathbbrm-is) explains if $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is additive and continuous then it is linear.